# Best way to Spell Check a web page

Tags: web, spell-checking

When adding text to a webpage best practice would be to use localization resources, or at least copy/paste text out of a program like Word (or any other grammar/spell checker).  That being said there are "always" a couple words here and there where a developer just "updates it."

My question, how do other people check for typos on their webpages?  I have a solution (Which I will post as a possible answer), but looking for other ideas.

Comment: I've just gone through 360 pages spell-checking them all. The answer below is good, but what I did was just open the page in Chrome, CTRL+A to select everything, copy it and then paste it into Word. It retains the vast majority of the page structure and the spelling/grammar checker in Word is good too. Using this method I found lots of typo and speling errors. Though I'm still going to have to do it multiple times in case I've missed anything (which I inevitably have). I think I may make a PHP script in my admin area that concatenates 25-or-so pages and then shows that so it goes a bit quicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a function in your javascript library to grab all text and put it in a textbox, which on a browser like chrome will then trigger the native spellchecker.

```
function SpellCheck()
{
    var ta=document.createElement('textarea'); 
    var s=document.createAttribute('style'); 
    s.nodeValue='width:100%;height:100em;'; 
    ta.setAttributeNode(s); 
    ta.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.body.innerText)); 
    document.body.appendChild(ta); 
    ta.focus(); 
    for (var i = 1; i <= ta.value.length; i++)
        ta.setSelectionRange(i, i);
}
```

Code from [@JohnLBevan](https://stackexchange.com/users/149392/johnlbevan) [blog post](http://developer42.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/button-to-spell-check-a-web-page-in-google-chrome/) (posted on 2011/03/28)

Answer (score 1):

I made the comment above, then I used the idea from the first answer to add this to my dev environment:

```
function showPageSource()
{
    var text = document.body.innerText;

    var textarea = document.createElement('TEXTAREA');
        textarea.style.position = 'absolute';
        textarea.style.opacity  = 0.95;
        textarea.style.zIndex = 999;
        textarea.style.top      = '25px';
        textarea.style.left     = '25px';
        textarea.style.width    = 'calc(100% - 50px)';
        textarea.style.height   = '500px';
        textarea.value          = text;
    document.body.appendChild(textarea);

    textarea.addEventListener('click',  function (e)
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }, false);

    document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e)
    {
        textarea.parentNode.removeChild(textarea);
    }, false);
}
```

And then a tag like this to show the sauce:

```
<a href="javascript:showPageSource()">SHOW PAGE SOURCE</a>
```

Shows a fair amount of crap from the navigation - but I can live with that.